# Does convexity implicate second derivate positive?

Tags: calculus

I've already prooved that if a function has the second derivative and it is positive so it convex, but the opposite is true?

Comment: A convex function may not even have a first derivative at some of the points.  E.g., $f(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Furthermore, "positive" is too strong a requirement.  There are convex functions whose 2nd derivative is zero, e.g., $g(x) = x$.

Comment: Fact, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment by @avs , a convex function need not be differentiable on its domain of definition. However, if the function is twice differentiable, then its derivative is nonnegative.